# Problems with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, case, sql-like

I have two tables...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `idcliente` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `movil` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dni` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `familiar` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compras` (
  `idcompra` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idcliente` INT(7) NOT NULL,
  `observacion` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcompra`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

In the following query, when the name is `none` the `LIKE` returns nothing.  How do I add the `like` to the `CASE WHEN`?

```
SELECT compras.idcompra, 
     CASE WHEN clientes.idcliente is null 
          THEN 'none' 
     ELSE CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido) END 
     AS nombre FROM compras 
left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
where CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ' ', clientes.apellido) LIKE '%none%' 
order by compras.idcompra asc
```

For example, when using the follow query...

```
select compras.idcompra, case when clientes.idcliente is null then 'none' else CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido) end as nombre from compras 
left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente)
```

... I get these results...

```
+----------+--------+
| idcompra | nombre |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | none   |
| 2        | none   |
| 3        | none   |
| 4        | juan   |
| 5        | pepe   |
+----------+--------+
```

However, the following query returns `0` rows. The `like` does not recognize `none`.

```
select compras.idcompra, case when clientes.idcliente is null then 'none' else CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido) end as nombre 
from compras left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
where CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ' ', clientes.apellido) LIKE '%none%' 
order by compras.idcompra asc
```

¡¡I need to return this!!

```
+----------+--------+
| idcompra | nombre |
+----------+--------+
| 1        | none   |
| 2        | none   |
| 3        | none   |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you just want to add the `like` condition from `where` to `case`? If not them give some sample data and expected output

Comment: Excuse me I do not speak English I want to enter a search value $ _POST [search] (none), but when I put 'none' it returns nothing.

Comment: Could you give some sample data? And your expected output based on that. So we can see what is wrong.

Comment: @Utsav Edit the main post. look up

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your query:

```
and '[search term]' != 'none'
```

Comment: I need to write 'none' ($_post[search]) to return records ¡I need you to return this!!
1-none
2-none
3-none

Answer (score 0):

Change your where clause. Use the same condition that from the case expression that returns 'none' which is  **clientes.idcliente is null**

```
SELECT compras.idcompra, 
     CASE WHEN clientes.idcliente is null 
          THEN 'none' 
     ELSE CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido) END AS nombre
FROM compras 
left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
where clientes.idcliente IS NULL
order by compras.idcompra asc
```

An alternative approach would be to form a derived table of your original query then filter on the results of your case expression, but I believe this would be less efficient than the suggestion above.

```
SELECT idcompra, nombre 
FROM (
        SELECT compras.idcompra, 
             CASE WHEN clientes.idcliente is null 
                  THEN 'none' 
             ELSE CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ',', clientes.apellido) END AS nombre 
        FROM compras 
        left join clientes  on (compras.idcliente=clientes.idcliente) 
        ) D
WHERE nombre = 'none'
order by idcompra asc
```

Comment: I enter a value in $ _POST [search]. if '$ _POST [search] =' pe '' would return 5-pepe. If it is 'ju' it would return 4-juan, if it is 'non', 1-none, 2-none, 3-none. That's why I need to use LIKE '% $ _ POST [search]%'. It is understood<br> `where CONCAT(clientes.nombre, ' ', clientes.apellido) LIKE '%$_POST[search]%'`

Comment: You cannot use the result of a case expression in the where clause of the same query. You must either use a "derived table" or use the condition(s) of the case expression. I suggest it is simpler to use the condition of the case expression. (*nb. my iniital response was incorrect and I fixed it soon after as i  had misread the question*)